# Redission-netty thread is not shutting down

Tags: java, multithreading, redis, netty, redisson

I am using Redission for locking purpose in spring which have the maven dependency version of 3.5.3 and netty-all dependency version of 4.1.22.final.
But my Java VisualVM showing that redission-netty thread is always in running stage . Can someone tell me the reason behind this.

[image]

Comment: Did you find anything related to this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `Redisson.shutdown` method during application shutdown process?

Comment: So all the 32 threads (by default) will be in `RUNNING` state until I call `Redisson.shutdown`?

Comment: Yes, since they were created by Redisson